# How to avoid unwanted imports on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Frequently, when writing variables with type `String`, after I write the type declaration, IJ adds automatically the following import:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
```

Afterward, when I assign a string value to the variable, I get the following error popup:

> Incompatible types:
>
> Required: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String
>
> Found: java.lang.String

After I remove the unwanted import, the problem is solved.  But this import keeps reappearing, not on every String I declare, but frequently enough to be a nuisance.

How to prevent IJ from inserting this import?

Comment: please follow the link ----> https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/excluding-classes-from-auto-import/

Comment: That fixed it. Thx!